# How to remove free form "tags" from domain-class?

Tags: grails

I've created 2 domain classes called Asset and Tag. Asset can have many Tags

```
// Asset.groovy
class Asset {
    static hasMany = [tags: Tag]
}

// Tag.groovy
class Tag {
    static belongsTo = Asset
    String word
}
```

The tags are entered into a textfield in the View, each separated by commas.

When the Asset form is submitted, the AssetController will use `Tag.findOrSaveWhere` to either create a new Tag or `Asset.addToTag`

```
def tags_list = params?.tags?.split(",")
tags_list.each {
    def tag = Tag.findOrSaveWhere(word: it.trim())
    assetInstance.addToTags(tag)
}
```

All that works very well, but I'm trying to essentially remove Tags from an Asset if the user updates and deleted a Tag.

How can I remove Tags on update?

**EDIT** I've gotten a little further with this by taking an old approach of deleting all the tags then attempting to save the Asset instance.

```
assetInstance.tags.clear()
def tags_list = params?.tags?.split(",")
tags_list.each {
    def tag = Tag.findOrSaveWhere(word: it.trim())
    assetInstance.addToTags(tag)
}
```

However, this will throw an exception if the Tags are null. In other words, if I delete all tags, saving fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. Clearing the tags in the update action was the right move, but I had to be mindful of the empty tags string from the form.

My end result was the following block in my `AssetController`

```
assetInstance.tags.clear()
def tags_list = params?.tags?.split(",")
tags_list.each {
def tag = Tag.findOrSaveWhere(word: it.trim())
if (tag.id != null) // to prevent null id exceptions
    assetInstance.addToTags(tag)
}
```